# Clickonce installations behaving different with .Net Framework 4.8

Tags: clickonce, .net-4.8

I have two applications that are installed through Clickonce. Recently we migrated both to .Net Framework 4.8. Now something odd is happening. One of the applications is asking for the spanish language pack before being installed. The other application is not (both running in the same computer). Both are running in the same Windows 7 SP1 machine.

In the project properties both have only "Microsoft .Net Framework 4.8 (x86 and x64)" as prerequisite.

Any ideas/hints about why both installations behave different?

Comment: That is supposed to be a feature.  Just make sure you selected the [publish language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-change-the-publish-language-for-a-clickonce-application?view=vs-2019) correctly.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, Hans. The publish language right now is left as "default" in both applications, which I guess picks the OS language that in this machine is spanish. But what puzzles me is why only one of the applications is asking for the language pack when installing.